# Required String parameter 'x' is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring API that I cannot change and it's post listener looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("upload")
    public String register(@RequestParam("x") String x, 
@RequestParam("y") String y) {//dostuff}
```

Now I have another Spring-boot API on my side that needs to send a POST request upon construction and the post request looks like this:

```
  String response = 
(String) rest.postForObject(url,objectWrapper,String.class);
```

and ObjectWrapper looks like this:

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
   private String x;
   private String y;

  public ObjectWrapper(String x, String y) {
      this.x= x;
      this.y = y;
     }
 }
```

when the above post request is executed, it throws exception from my side

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 null

When posting from postman with JSON/application, the error is required string parameter 'x' is not present.

However, when x and y are in params and not in the body it is sent successfully from postman.

also it is successful when I hardcode this in Spring as part of the url in the post request

```
  url + "/upload?x=test&y=test"
```

My question is, how can I send the two string over Post request from my Spring server to the other. I cannot change the listener. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters used as `@RequestParam` are query parameters and cannot be passed in the requestBody as you have done. They need to be appended to the url dynamically. That can be done in the below way.

```
  String url = baseUrl + "/upload?x={x}&y={y}";

  Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap();
  uriVariables.put("x", "valueForX");
  uriVariables.put("y", "valueForY");

  String response = rest.postForObject(url, null, String.class, uriVariables);
```

Here the RequestBody is nullable and since your API doesn't accept any requestBody, it is specified as null.

The documentation of the **postForObject** method can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-).

You may even use Spring's **UriBuilder** to build a url with queryParams. More on that can be found in its documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriBuilder.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what is the usage of @RequestParam. The variables are intended to be in the url (/upload?x=test&y=test is okay), not in the body.

If you want to put this variables in the body, chose a format (for exemple JSON), create an object, put json in the body, and mark the object as @RequestBody :

```
@PostMapping("upload")
public String register(@RequestBody MyObj myObj) {//dostuff}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Assuming that the person providing the API listener is expecting to have these in the URL, given that x and y's values would be different, how could I dynamicly change the url with x and y's right values?